# SBT plugin: How to list files output by incremental recompilation

Tags: scala, plugins, sbt, incremental-compiler

I am writing a plugin for SBT that requires a list of the class files generated by the last run of the Scala compiler.

This list of class files is then passed into a program that performs some bytecode transformations. Since this transformation process can be slow, I only want the class files written by the last run of the Scala compiler (i.e. those that there modified), not all class files in the output directory.

How can I obtain a list of the files last generated by the `compile` task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you cannot get this information directly from the `Analysis` object returned by the `compile` task.

However, what you could do is
to check `analysis.relations.allProducts` for changes. If any of the files is modified you can execute yours task, which performs bytecode transformations.

You could use a modified version of a [FileFunction.cached](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/faq.html#how-can-a-task-avoid-redoing-work-if-the-input-files-are-unchanged), to check for changes.

```
def cached(cacheBaseDirectory: File, inStyle: FilesInfo.Style)(action: Set[File] => Unit): Set[File] => Unit = {
  import Path._
  lazy val inCache = Difference.inputs(cacheBaseDirectory / "in-cache", inStyle)
  inputs => {
    inCache(inputs) { inReport =>
      if(!inReport.modified.isEmpty) action(inReport.modified)
    }   
  }     
}
```

The function takes following parameters:

- `cacheBaseDirectory` - location of the cache
- `inStyle` - description of how the changes should be discovered (see [sbt.FilesInfo](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.2/api/index.html#sbt.FilesInfo$) for possible options)
- `action` - a function run, when the files has been modified. The function takes a list of modified files as an argument.

The function returns another function which is run only if the set of files passed to it as an argument is modified.

#### Example

```
val transformBytecode = taskKey[Unit]("Transforms bytecode of modified files")

def cached(cacheBaseDirectory: File, inStyle: FilesInfo.Style)(action: Set[File] => Unit): Set[File] => Unit = {
  import Path._
  lazy val inCache = Difference.inputs(cacheBaseDirectory / "in-cache", inStyle)
  inputs => {
    inCache(inputs) { inReport =>
      if(!inReport.modified.isEmpty) action(inReport.modified)
    }   
  }     
}

transformBytecode <<= Def.task {
  val analysis = (compile in Compile).value
  val cachedFunction = cached(streams.value.cacheDirectory / "transform-bytecode", FilesInfo.lastModified) { modified =>
    // here you want to run the bytecode transformations on `modified` files
    println(s"Modified files $modified")
  }
  cachedFunction(analysis.relations.allProducts.toSet)
}.triggeredBy(compile in Compile)
```

Comment: Thanks for the carefully thought-out response. I as wondering why this wasn't working with SBT 0.13, but then (eventually) saw this in the change log: "Tasks that need a directory for storing cache information can now use the `cacheDirectory` method on `streams`.  This supersedes the `cacheDirectory` setting." I'm not sure what the fix is for SBT 0.13, but am investigating.

Comment: My previous comment wasn't correct: Whilst this works with SBT 0.13, `cacheDirectory` is still deprecated. The fix is to use `streams.value.cacheDirectory`. Thanks again for the excellent answer!

Comment: @AndrewBate thanks for your comment, you're absolutely right, the `streams.value.cacheDirectory` is a way to go. I've updated my answer to match your findings.