# how to cache the results of an sbt TaskKey?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have an expensive task that I need to reference in my tests

```
lazy val exampleSources = TaskKey[Seq[File]]("exampleSources", "for use in tests")

exampleSources := (updateClassifiers in Test).value.select(
  artifact = artifactFilter(classifier = "sources")
)
```

(and then I can pass `exampleSources.value` as a parameter to my forked tests)

However, every time I run a test, this task is called, and `updateClassifiers` (expensive) is called. But I'm happy caching the value on first call and then using that for the session.

Without writing the cache myself, is there any way to do this using built-in sbt objects?

UPDATE: this doesn't work. Second evaluation has `CACHE=true` but the resolution tasks still run.

```
lazy val infoForTests = TaskKey[Seq[String]]("infoForTests", "for use in tests")

val infoForTestsCache = collection.mutable.Buffer[String]()

infoForTests := {
  println("CACHE=" + infoForTestsCache.nonEmpty)
  if (infoForTestsCache.isEmpty) {
    infoForTestsCache ++= Seq[String](
      "-Densime.compile.jars=" + jars((fullClasspath in Compile).value),
      "-Densime.test.jars=" + jars((fullClasspath in Test).value),
      "-Densime.compile.classDirs=" + classDirs((fullClasspath in Compile).value),
      "-Densime.test.classDirs=" + classDirs((fullClasspath in Test).value),
      "-Dscala.version=" + scalaVersion.value,
      // sorry! this puts a source/javadoc dependency on running our tests
      "-Densime.jars.sources=" + (updateClassifiers in Test).value.select(
        artifact = artifactFilter(classifier = "sources")
      ).mkString(",")
    )
    println("CACHE=" + infoForTestsCache.nonEmpty)
  }
  infoForTestsCache
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`FileFunction.cached`](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/faq.html#how-can-a-task-avoid-redoing-work-if-the-input-files-are-unchanged) to cache the results and doing work only if input changes.

Just an example from linked sbt documentation:

```
// define a task that takes some inputs
//   and generates files in an output directory
myTask := {
    // wraps a function taskImpl in an uptodate check
    //   taskImpl takes the input files, the output directory,
    //   generates the output files and returns the set of generated files
    val cachedFun = FileFunction.cached(cacheDirectory.value / "my-task") { (in: Set[File]) =>
      taskImpl(in, target.value) : Set[File]
    }
    // Applies the cached function to the inputs files
    cachedFun(inputs.value)
}
```

You may also want to check my answer to a similar question : [How to list files output by incremental recompilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23873031/sbt-plugin-how-to-list-files-output-by-incremental-recompilation/23876075#23876075).

Comment: hmm, well I don't have any inputs so I guess my input is `()`. I'll take a closer look at this shortly.

Comment: This doesn't work for me because I'm not reading or writing `File`s